# Android AlertDialog underline text in list

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, underline

I have an AlertDialog which displays different items in a list. Now I want some of these items to be italic and some underlined. How is it possible? Do I really need to create a custom AlertDialog?

My code:

```
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] splitted = response.split("\\|");
    for(String name:splitted) {
        names.add(name.split("\\+")[1]);
    }
    String[] items = new String[names.size()];
    items = names.toArray(items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Onlineliste");
    builder.setItems(items, null);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will have to make a custom alert dialog

For **UNDERLINE**

```
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags()|Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG)
```

For **ITALIC**

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC)
```

Comment: There's no TextView?!

Comment: You'll have to create a custom dialog and set underlined and italic as per your requirement in your dialog

Comment: But then I need a costum Listview too, how do I do this?

Comment: Yes a custom listview with just one textview and set the properties of the textview as mentioned above as per your requirement.

Comment: And what's about the case when I want 1 item italic and 1 item underlined? That's not possible with just one textview :/

Comment: @Phil It's possible since your listview layout will contain only one text view but it'll be inflated for every row, so programmatically you can set one sa Italic and one as underlined.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public class Common_SingleLine_Alert extends Dialog implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    Button okBtn;
    TextView messagetv;
    String messageStr;

    public Common_SingleLine_Alert(Context context, Spannable message) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.messageStr = message;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.marker_info_window);

        okBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
        messagetv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);

        messagetv.setText(messageStr);

        okBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        dismiss();

    }

}
```

// the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/themeColor" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okBtn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/address"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/reverse_common_button_selection"
            android:text="@android:string/ok" 
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

// how to use it

```
dialog = new Common_SingleLine_Alert(this, getResources()
                    .getString(Html.fromHtml("<i>Name</i>")));
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setOnDismissListener(new Dialog.OnDismissListener() {

                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface d) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: I don't mean the title, I mean the different items

Comment: Html.fromHtml("<b>Title</b><br><i>Description here</i>").toString();

Comment: Look pls, there is .setItems(items, null); and there is no way to do this Html.fromHtml

Comment: You have create an ArrayList of string just create an Array list with this Html.fromHtml("<b>Title</b><br><i>Description here</i>").toString()

Comment: I sorry I did not recognize the toString() but this simply does nothing, no Styling or anything

Comment: Then you have to create custom alert with textview and then use this code

Comment: I have change my answer